# Patent Number suffix A1 / B2 etc.

Tags: uspto, number

On some patent numbers I see an "A1" / "A2" / "B2" etc. suffix after the actual patent number

e.g. "USxxxxxxxxx B2" or "WOxxxxxxxx A1" etc.

What do these suffixes mean? Is there a key somewhere that lists what they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are kind codes. They are effectively version numbers for published versions of the patent application. Every country has their own set of kind codes, but typically an A code (such as A1) represents a patent application, and a B code (such as B2) represents a granted patent.

The background behind this system is provided in WIPO's standard [ST.16](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/standards/en/pdf/03-16-01.pdf). WIPO also maintains a [list](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/standards/en/pdf/07-03-02.pdf) of the actual codes used by each country.